# How Alamofire could guarantee response method would be called after get all the response?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession, alamofire

Recently I read the source code of **Alamofire**, and I am really confused about How could **Alamofire** guarantee the response method would be called in correctly order. I hope someone(maybe **matt** lol) could help me out.

Example, an easy GET Request like this

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events")
```

After I analysed the work flow of it, I posted my understanding

1. **Create** the **request** and underlying **NSURLSession**.

   ```
    public func request(method: Method, URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL) -> Request {
      return Manager.sharedInstance.request(method, URLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding)
    }
   ```

   This method would create a **request: Request** object, which would contain the underlying **NSURLSessionDataTask** object. **Manager.sharedInstance** has already set up a **NSURLSession** and set itself as that session's delegate. The **Manager.sharedInstance** object would save a customized object **request.delegate** in its own property **delegate**
2. After those objects were created, **Alamofire** would send this request immediately.

   ```
   public func request(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> Request {
     var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?
     dispatch_sync(queue) {
       dataTask = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(URLRequest.URLRequest)
     }

     let request = Request(session: session, task: dataTask!)
     delegate[request.delegate.task] = request.delegate

     if startRequestsImmediately {
       request.resume()
     }

     return request
   }
   ```
3. Since **Manager.sharedInstance** set itself as the underlying **NSURLSession**'s delegate, when data received, the delegate methods would be called

   ```
   public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
       if dataTaskDidReceiveData != nil {
           dataTaskDidReceiveData!(session, dataTask, data)
       } else if let delegate = self[dataTask] as? Request.DataTaskDelegate {
           delegate.URLSession(session, dataTask: dataTask, didReceiveData: data)
       }
   }
   ```
4. If a user want to get the response and do something related, he would use following public API

   ```
   // Here the request is a Request object
   self.request?.responseString { (request, response, body, error) in
       // Something do with the response
   }
   ```
5. let's see what the **responseString(_: completionHandler:)** method does

   ```
   public func response(queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil, serializer: Serializer, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
     delegate.queue.addOperationWithBlock {
       let (responseObject: AnyObject?, serializationError: NSError?) = serializer(self.request, self.response, self.delegate.data)

       dispatch_async(queue ?? dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           completionHandler(self.request, self.response, responseObject, self.delegate.error ?? serializationError)
       }
     }

     return self
   }
   ```

My question is how **5** could be guaranteed to happen after **3**, so the user could get all the response not part of it, because **self.response** at this time would be fully loaded.

Is it because of NSURLSession's background processing occurs on the same queue -- **delegate.queue**, which is created like this in **Alamofire**:

```
//class Request.TaskDelegate: NSObject, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate
self.queue = {
  let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
  operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
  operationQueue.suspended = true

  if operationQueue.respondsToSelector("qualityOfService") {
    operationQueue.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfService.Utility
  }

  return operationQueue
}()
```

Is my understanding correct, how does that happen? It might be require some understanding about **RunLoop** and **NSURLSession's thread mechanism**, if you could point out where I could refer to, thank you as well.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question but note that in your last code snippet the operation queue is set as suspended when it is created.  This will prevent any operations that are added to it from running until it is unsuspended.  I suspect it is unsuspended once the task has received all the response data, so the block added in #5 won't be executed until the full response has been received.

Comment: Hi, dan you are correct! This solved the problem!